# Given 2 strings and integer k, convert one string into another in exactly k steps

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am solving a problem on the "HackerRank" page, specifically the problem called "Append and Delete", but I cannot make all the cases correct.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/append-and-delete/problem

> "You have a string of lowercase English alphabetic letters. You can
>   perform two types of operations on the string:
>
> Append a lowercase English alphabetic letter to the end of the string.
>   Delete the last character in the string. Performing this operation on
>   an empty string results in an empty string. Given an integer, , and
>   two strings,  and , determine whether or not you can convert  to  by
>   performing exactly  of the above operations on . If it's possible,
>   print Yes. Otherwise, print No.
>
> For example, strings  and . Our number of moves, . To convert  to , we
>   first delete all of the characters in  moves. Next we add each of the
>   characters of  in order. On the  move, you will have the matching
>   string. If there had been more moves available, they could have been
>   eliminated by performing multiple deletions on an empty string. If
>   there were fewer than  moves, we would not have succeeded in creating
>   the new string.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the appendAndDelete function in the editor below. It should
>   return a string, either Yes or No.
>
> appendAndDelete has the following parameter(s):
>
> s: the initial string t: the desired string k: an integer that
>   represents the number of operations".

```
int cont = 0;
        int limite = 0;


        if (s.length() < t.length()){
            limite += s.length();
        } else if (s.length() >= t.length()){
            limite += t.length();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++){

            if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)){

                cont += 2;

            }

        }

        int diferen = 0;

        if (s.length() != t.length()){

            diferen += (Math.abs(t.length() - s.length()));

        } 

        cont += diferen;

        if(cont <= k){

            return "Yes";

        } else {
            return "No";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

To spot an issue in your code, let's simplify it.

#### Simplify `limite` calculation

To calculate a `limite` value, you use an `if/else` block as below:

```
if (s.length() < t.length()){
    limite += s.length();
} else if (s.length() >= t.length()){
    limite += t.length();
}
```

However, since your `limite` is always `0` before this block and what you're looking for is a length of the shortest string, you can simply replace it with:

```
int limite = Math.min(s.length(), t.length());
```

#### Simplify `diferen` calculation

Again, you don't need any `if` block to calculate your `diferen` - if Both strings have equal length then the `diferen` is simply `0` and that's what `Math.abs(t.length() - s.length())` will also yield.

So, instead of having this:

```
int diferen = 0;
if (s.length() != t.length()) {
    diferen += (Math.abs(t.length() - s.length()));
}
```

You can simply have a one-liner:

```
int diferen = (Math.abs(t.length() - s.length()));
```

#### Better variable names

Your variables names like `diferen` or `cont` or `limite` are confusing. Instead, you could rename these variables to `absLengthDifference`, `operationCount` and `commonLength`.

#### Your simplified code

```
static String appendAndDelete(String s, String t, int k) {
    int operationCount = 0;

    int shorterStringLength = Math.min(s.length(), t.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)) {
            operationCount += 2;
        }
    }

    int absLengthDifference = (Math.abs(t.length() - s.length()));
    operationCount += absLengthDifference;

    if(operationCount <= k) {
        return "Yes";
    } 

    return "No";
}
```

### Finding logical errors

So, based on modifications made in the **Introduction**, we will figure out why the program produces the wrong result.

Let's consider an input like below:

> ab
>
> bb
>
> 2

Your program will give a positive verdict to this because `operationCount` will be `2` but `operationCount <= 2`. So, it's not correct because in order to convert `ab` to `bb` using operations in the task, we must perform the following:

> 'ab' -> 'a' | the only way to get to 'a' is to remove 'b'
>
> 'a'  -> ''  | the only way to correct 'a' is to remove it first
>
> ''  -> 'b'  | and then append 'b'
>
> 'b' -> 'bb' | finally, append 'b' again

As you can see, it took us `4` operations to achieve the desired result, not `2`. Hence, the block below is wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)) {
        operationCount += 2;
    }
}
```

**It's not enough to add** `2`. If you find a mismatch you must remove all characters from the end to get to it (as seen in the example).

Additionally, `if(operationCount <= k)` is wrong because the number of operations must be exactly `k`.

### Fixing solution

1. The first thing to realize is that if `k` is larger or equal to the sum of string lengths then the answer is `Yes`. We can remove all the characters from the original string `s` and keep removing a character from an empty string `0` or more times and then append characters from the destination string `t`.
2. Otherwise, if find a length `commonLength` of the common string for both, then we can convert `s` into `t` in `s.length() + t.length() - 2*commonLength` steps. That value `minOperationCount`, however, cannot be greater than `k` for obvious reasons. Also, if it's less than `k`, then `k - minOperationCount` must be multiple of `2`. IF it's not then it's possible to do the conversion in exactly `k` steps.

### Code

```
// Complete the appendAndDelete function below.
static String appendAndDelete(String s, String t, int k) {
    int totalLength = s.length() + t.length();
    if (totalLength <= k) {
        return "Yes";
    }

    int commonLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <  Math.min(s.length(), t.length()); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i)) {
            break;
        }
        commonLength++;
    }  
    int minOperationCount = totalLength - 2 * commonLength;

    if(minOperationCount <= k && ((k - minOperationCount) % 2 == 0)) {
        return "Yes";
    } 

    return "No";
}
```